# Simulink parameter setting

Tags: matlab, simulink

Can someone tell me how the simulink example sldemo_clutch.mdl sets FromWorkSpace parameters such as Tin and Fn? They are "Clutch Pedal" and "Engine Torque" blocks. I don't think they are set in the PostLoadFcn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're in the Model Workspace, not the Base Workspace.  Look at View->Model Explorer->Model Workspace to view them.